# Click event for List items instead of Button using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call the function on clicking on List item using Angular JS. But, its not getting called. But, its working for a button.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')"   translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN" class="ng-scope">english</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('de')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_DE" class="ng-scope">espanol</button>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <div>Select Language</div>

    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/16.png"><a href="">English</a></li>
        <li><img src="img/13.png"><a href=""  ng-click="changeLanguage('de')"  >Español</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('at', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', { // Translate w.r.t English.

        BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'English',
        BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'Espa&ntilde;ol',
        Charcoal:'Charcoal Hoodie',
        CrestCrewNeck:'Crest Crew Neck',
        GeoLoveCrewNeck:'Geo Love Crew Neck',
        NavyHoodie:'Navy Hoodie',
        BrainiacTShirt:'Brainiac T Shirt',
        CrestTShirt:'Crest T Shirt',
        GeometricTShirt:'Geometric T Shirt',
        SellMoreManTShirt:'Sell More Man T Shirt'

    });
    $translateProvider.translations('de', { // Translate w.r.t Spanish.
        BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'Englisch',
        BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'Espa&ntilde;ol',
        Charcoal: 'Hoodie carbón',
        CrestCrewNeck:'Cresta del cuello de equipo',
        GeoLoveCrewNeck:'Geo amor del cuello de equipo',
        NavyHoodie:'Hoodie Navy',
        BrainiacTShirt:'Brainiac T Shirt',
        CrestTShirt:'Cresta T Shirt',
        GeometricTShirt:'Geométrico  T Shirt',
        SellMoreManTShirt:'Vender más hombre T Shirt'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en'); // On page load with English content.
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) { // Inject $translate.
   $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {        
    $translate.uses(key); // Based on the Key.
};
});
```

Can you please check the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that Your list is not under controller

*Your code*

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <!--Your controller scope-->
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/16.png"><a href="">English</a></li>
        <li><img src="img/13.png"><a href=""  ng-click="changeLanguage('de')"  >Español</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Change it to*, Bring `nav` div under controller

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')"   translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN" class="ng-scope">english</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('de')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_DE" class="ng-scope">espanol</button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div>Select Language</div>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="img/16.png"><a href="">English</a></li>
            <li><img src="img/13.png"><a href=""  ng-click="changeLanguage('de')"  >Español</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```